# How to restrict user posting a node in certain circumstances

Tags: users, nodes

I've created a new user role (country_admin) and I have created a field for these users called user_country. This can be set when registering a user to UK or USA.

I have created a taxonomy 'Countries' and have added UK and USA as terms. I have also created a term reference on my articles so that articles can be assigned to a country.

The functionality I require is that only the user who has UK in the user_country field can post an article with the term set to UK.

I am looking at hook_node_access_records() and hook_node_grants() and have got the functionality working so UK users can only VIEW or UPDATE UK articles using this, however, in hook_node_grants() there doesn't seem to be an "ADD" operation.

How would I do this?

Current hook_node_grants() below

```
/**
* Implements hook_node_grants().
*/
function curator_scraper_node_grants($account, $op) {
    if ($op == 'view') {
        if (array_key_exists(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID, $account->roles)) {

            //Let's get the country id the user is linked with
            $uid = $account->uid;
            $user = user_load($uid);
            $country = $user->field_user_country['und'][0];

            $grants[MYMODULE_REALM] = array(
                MYMODULE_GRANT_ID_PUBLIC, // Allow public data
                $country, // this should be users' country link
            );
        }
        else {
            // this is an anonymous user, give them the 'public' grant ID
            // that allows them access to public nodes
            $grants[MYMODULE_REALM] = array(
                MYMODULE_GRANT_ID_PUBLIC,
            );
        }
    }
    if ($op == 'update'){
        //We can grant update permissions here similar to the above
        // but where is $op == "add"???
    }
    return $grants;

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to reinvent the Organic Groups module. Have you reviewed what it does before writing your own code?

Comment: In a nutshell, I would rather write my own code. I currently build WP plugins and am now learning Drupal module development. I'm not building a site - more of a learning exercise.

Comment: OK, then, in that case I would suggest you look at altering the form (to remove options that don't apply because not allowed). IIRC hook_node_grants() only applies to items already in the database, and doesn't affect saving.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Node access user reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) module:

> Gives content access permissions to users for content that references
>   the users with User reference or Entity reference.
>
> This is great if you want your content authors to be able to choose
>   additional authors, or choose who can view their content, as well as
>   being able to display the list of authors or viewers within your
>   content, or in views displays.